# How to fix "There is no cloudservices robot account for your project. Please ensure that the Dataflow API is enabled for your project."

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, terraform-provider-gcp

We are using Terraform to deploy the resouce "google_dataflow_job" on Google Cloud.
We did a successfully deployement few weeks ago (Dataflow API is already enabled since years).

We now get this error when we are executing a "terraform plan"

`Error: Error when reading or editing Dataflow job 2020-10-07_06_20_01-18099947630909311965: googleapi: Error 400: (10a8bef84dbdde13): There is no cloudservices robot account for your project.  Please ensure that the Dataflow API is enabled for your project., failedPrecondition`

We have theses accounts:
[image: IAM accounts]

Does anyone know how to add this cloudservices robot account?

Comment: Can you provide more context for that error? During which operation does it occur? What service account have you specified?

Comment: Just curious - is the service account also being provisioned by the same `terraform plan`? Or are you using a pre-existing one?

Comment: I've found a longer version of a similar exception, see if it helps: https://pastebin.com/raw/y1cgkufT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error when running terraforms and it seems to be solved when recreating the job.

**I did the following steps:**

1. Cancel the job from the console
2. Remove the job from terraform state
3. rerun terraform in order to create the dataflow job again